# onGetErrorMessage not being called for FluentUIReact TextField

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-fabric

I was going through fabric UI TextField documentation(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/textfield ) . I tried few examples of TextField with the following two handlers:-

1. onChange
2. onGetErrorMessage.

I tried few experiments with these two handlers (https://codepen.io/nishchay271095/pen/rNyPKYY?editors=1011 ):-

Case 1. When using both the handlers without any extra properties of TextField, both handlers(onChange and onGetErrorMessage) are called.

```
     <TextField
        label="Controlled TextField"
        onChange={onChangeSecondTextFieldValue}
        onGetErrorMessage = {onGetErrorMessageHandler}
      />
```

Case 2. When using both handlers with "defaultValue" property, both handlers(onChange and onGetErrorMessage) are called.

```
      <TextField
        label="Controlled TextField"
        defaultValue = "hello"
        onChange={onChangeSecondTextFieldValue}
        onGetErrorMessage = {onGetErrorMessageHandler}
      />
```

Case 3. When using both handlers with "value" property of TextField, **only onChange() handler was called.**

```
    <TextField
        label="Controlled TextField"
        value="hello"
        onChange={onChangeSecondTextFieldValue}
        onGetErrorMessage = {onGetErrorMessageHandler}
      />
```

Now, I'm having following doubts:-

1. **Why onGetErrorMessage() is not being called in case 3?**
2. **How value and defaultValue properties affect the behavior of these two handlers(onChange and onGetErrorMessage)?**

Answer (score 1):

> Why onGetErrorMessage() is not being called in case 3?

When you have `Uncontrolled Component` there is no reason to use `value` property and `onChange` function, because `TextField Component` treats `defaultValue` as initial and it creates local state variable `uncontrolledValue` which interacts like when you have value prop.

So, in your case you have `Uncontrolled Component` and value property is excess.

**Uncontrolled Component:**

```
<TextField
  defaultValue="Hello"
  onGetErrorMessage={value => {
   if (value === 'Foo') {
     return 'Foo is not valid value';
   }
  }}
/>
```

**Controlled Component**

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('Hello');

<TextField
  value={inputValue}
  onChange={(_, newValue) => {
    if(newValue || newValue === '') {
      setInputValue(newValue)
    }
  }}
  onGetErrorMessage={value => {
   if (value === 'Foo') {
     return 'Foo is not valid value';
   }
  }}
/>
```

> How value and defaultValue properties affect the behavior of these two handlers(onChange and onGetErrorMessage)?

Answer lies in [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/textfield):

**defaultValue:**

*Default value of the text field. Only provide this if the text field is an uncontrolled component; otherwise, use the value property.*

**value:**

*Current value of the text field. Only provide this if the text field is a controlled component where you are maintaining its current state; otherwise, use the defaultValue property.*

Full working example [Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/KKWLjjv?editors=1111).